# Deriving Confidence Interval from pivotal statistic

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

Using the pivotal statistic $T = \frac{Y ̄ −μ}{s/\sqrt{n}}$ derive the $(1 − α)100%$ confidence interval for the mean $μ$, where a random sample of size $n$ is taken from a very large population and $Y ∼ N(μ,σ)$.

Comment: Please read the `self study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Find $t_{{n-1},\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ from tables or [here.](http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc3/calc.aspx?id=10)

then get CI at $(1-\alpha)100$ level.
$$\bar{Y}\pm t_{{n-1},\frac{\alpha}{2}}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Note:- $t_n\sim N(0,1)~for~n\rightarrow\infty$